# Ant release script

Tags: ant

Please see the blow script for doing the backup of current ear and replacing it with new version.

```
<move todir="/usr/local/jboss/server/default/ear_bk/" includeEmptyDirs="yes" verbose="true">
    <fileset dir="/usr/local/jboss/release/server/default/deploy/tgr_10_10L_0036.ear" >
            <include name="**/*" />
    </fileset>
</move>

 <copy todir="/usr/local/jboss/server/default/deploy/">
     <fileset dir="/usr/local/jboss/release/server/default/deploy/tgr_10_10L_0037.ear"/>
 </copy>

</target>
```

Issue:
1) Only the content of the tgr_10_10L_0036.ear is moved to ear_bk. How to move the tgr_10_10L_0036.ear?.

2) How to copy the complete tgr_10_10L_0037.ear directory to usr/local/jboss/server/default/deploy/ instead only the content ?

Comment: to get more solution/comment please accept the best answers for your prevous questions

Answer (score 0):

Simple quick fix is providing tgr_10_10L_0037.ear in todir

```
<copy todir="/usr/local/jboss/server/default/deploy/tgr_10_10L_0037.ear/">
     <fileset dir="/usr/local/jboss/release/server/default/deploy/tgr_10_10L_0037.ear"/>
 </copy>
```

for this you need to create tgr_10_10L_0037.ear before copying files

```
<mkdir dir="/usr/local/jboss/server/default/deploy/tgr_10_10L_0037.ear/"/>
```

Comment: Any option to exclude the tgr_10_10L_0037.ear directory name from the fileset.  EX:- <fileset dir="/usr/local/jboss/release/server/default/deploy"/>

Comment: <exclude name="**/tgr_10_10L_0037.ear" />. In this **/ indicates it will exclude tgr_10_10L_0037.ear if it is available in sub directories also.  Put this exclude with in <filset> tag like  <fileset ....> <exlude ... /> </fileset>

Comment: seems ok in the case of copy. But I want to move the ear to backup directory. I this case directory will not get removed from the deploy directory and I don't want to delete the directory as with out ensuring the ear has completely moved to backup directory.